# should i use the joomla user profile table?

Tags: database, joomla

When Joomla 1.6 came out and onwards I started using the joomla profile plugin to manage my user's profile data.

I have been wondering for quite a while about the pros and cons of such a table where the data is stored in rows and not in fields.

The pro is definitely that I can add new profile fields very easily.

The con is how do you search on the information when different field types are stored in a text field - ie: the dob of the user is stored in a text field.

Perhaps this question is more database than joomla related?

But it boils down to - should I be using the joomla profile table for large numbers of users?

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the project you are working on.

If you use a plugin to get the work done, cons are

- You will have to spend some time to get to know the plugin.
- It will take more time to make changes since you don't know the internal structure of the plugin.

pros are,

- Plugin does everything for you. Faster development.
- Most probably error free and tested well.

In my opinion if you are to do a lot of data manipulation and if the plugin does what you want to do exactly use the plugin. That's the best part of joomla. Faster development. If you have any problems please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Joomla extended profile if you want to, or you can use [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/210) which also extends user profiles.

Out of all honest, might be better for lots of users, as you might want to install other extensions in the future, such as the Kunena forum for example, which it integrates with fully, along with lots of other extensions.

Comment: Hi Lodder, 
Thanks for the info. I suspect it is more of a database question than a joomla question.
Mat

Comment: well, not really. It's a matter of both to be honest. What is the main question you want answered? Might be easier to give a more detailed answer ;)